# Breaking string in to two lines in controller and send to view ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to know, There is a string that I want to break the value into two lines and set into the model, and pass it to the view.

In the view, it should be shown as 2 lines in the Text Area.

Is this possible to do?

This is the value that I want to break. I tried this

```
taskMain.Note = CustAddress.ToUpper() +" "+ custHouseNo.ToUpper() + " " + City.ToUpper() + " " + provinceCode.ToUpper() + ", " + Country.ToUpper() + "<br/><br/>Customer Contact No : " + CustPhoneNumnber;
```

I want to break it into two lines from `Customer Contact Number`. The above is printed in one line with string

This is the view.

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 form-group"> 
   @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Note, 10, 400, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "TaskNote", placeholder = "Type Additional Notes here" }) 
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Note, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) 
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `\n\n` instead of `<br/><br/>`. This works for me. But I really do not know if this is the best solution to the proplem.

Comment: @JonasWeinhardt Hi.. It worked. Thanks a lot. Please post your reply as an answer. I will vote it.

Comment: No problem. Glad my solution works for you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `<br/><br/>` to break up the string you can use `\n\n` like this:

```
taskMain.Note = CustAddress.ToUpper() +" "+ custHouseNo.ToUpper() + " " + City.ToUpper() + " " + provinceCode.ToUpper() + ", " + Country.ToUpper() + "\n\nCustomer Contact No : " + CustPhoneNumnber;
```